# Dust.js Implemenation, If template is hardcoded or to be fetched from other location, if JSON is hardcoded or to be fetched

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache, dust.js

As the title clearly states I want to implement [dust.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) in my application.

I created a function called `tmplReplaceContent` that accepts 3 parameters `template`, `json`, `target`

I've worked it out in [mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/) too, which I think I got bugs on, took me about 10 hours, but still no luck in debugging what is wrong. So I decided to shift to *dust* , but also because of its good feats.

Now, for the question again, I want to check whether the `template` is a path or **dust template**, if it is a path, then `$.get` it, if it is a template, then just use it, same goes for the `json`, if it is a path do `$.getJSON` else use it as it is.

Here is my *mustache* implementation, as you can see, the regex only checks for single `{{template}}` and will not work if I have complex template, if it is troublesome to do a complex check, I will be just fetching all the templates from a file.

```
tmplReplaceContent : function(json, tmpl, target) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\{{[a-zA-Z\.\_]*\}}"),
    view = '';
    function setOutput(template) {
        var content = Mustache.render(template, view);
        $(target).html(content).hide().fadeIn();
    }
    function doJSON(json) {
        view = json;
        if(!regex.test(tmpl)){
            /* get mustache tmpl from the path */
            $.get(msi.vars.tmpl_url + tmpl + '.mustache', setOutput);
        } else {
            setOutput(tmpl);
        }
    }
    /* json -> check if object */
    if (typeof json === 'object') {
        doJSON(json);
    } else {
        /* getJSON from the path */
        $.getJSON(msi.vars.base_url + json, doJSON);
    }
}
```

Do you have anything in mind that is better than the implementation I thought? What are the downside of this implementation? Thanks!

**EDIT** : 
example of a tmpl as path :

```
templates/default
```

or can be

```
default
```

for I have setup the implementation `msi.vars.tmpl_url = base_url + 'public/templates/'`

Comment: So `tmpl` might be a URL? Can you post a sample?

Comment: edit: Added example . :D

Comment: Why don't you just pass `template` and `path` as separate variables?

Comment: `tmpl` can be either a template or a path. Why don't you just make a separate variable for a path and check to see which one was defined?